# How can I select all rows in a table, and cross-check it with another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

### MySQL Tables

**MySQL: Plants**

```
+----+--------+
| id | plant  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | tree   |
+----+--------+
| 2  | flower |
+----+--------+
| 3  | tree   |
+----+--------+
```

**MySQL: Trees**

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 1  | hard |
+----+------+
| 3  | soft |
+----+------+
```

### What I'm trying to do

I want to select all rows in the table **plants**.

But if `plant = tree`, then the type in the table **trees** must be `hard` in order for it to be displayed.

So, the example above should output: `1=tree` and `2=flower`.

`3=tree` should be excluded because its `type = soft`.

### What I've tried so far...but didn't work

a) I guess I cannot use `union`, because the columns are different.

b) I already tried `left join`, but that didn't work either:

```
select p.id, p.plant
from plants AS p
left join
(
   select `id`, `type`
   from `trees`
) AS t ON p.id = t.id
WHERE t.type = 'hard'
```

any ideas on how I can do it?

Comment: Why don't you store `type` in plants table? A tree cannot be both hard and soft at the same time, i think..

Comment: @dinobeytar, true, but I've also stored some other information in both tables (I just didn't include it in the example above so I wouldn't confuse anyone), and I wanted to have these information stored separately. But thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes

```
select p.id, p.plant from plants as p left join trees as t on (p.id = t.id) where t.type = 'hard' or t.type is null
```

I hope this works. Anyway the problem with your current query is not the left join (that is ok actually), but that you specify the tree type must be hard so you eliminate the rows with null tree that the left join gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
select p.id, p.plant, t.id as tree_id, t.type from plants p left join trees t ON (p.id = t.id) WHERE t.type = 'hard'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.plant
FROM plants AS p
LEFT JOIN trees AS t ON p.id = t.id
WHERE t.type = 'hard'
   OR t.type IS NULL
```